# How do i get the xpath of an element in selenium?

Tags: python

Getpath is a function that isn't working for me. this is the following error i get:

```
xpath = html_tree.getroottree().getpath(element)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, 
got WebElement)
```

i imported

```
from lxml import etree
```

and installed with

```
pip install lxml
```

this is the code i used

```
# Find the element with the desired content
element = driver_global.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(),'{keyword}')]")
outer_html = element.get_attribute("outerHTML")

print(f"element {element}")
print(f"outer_html {outer_html}")

# Parse the HTML source code
html_tree = etree.HTML(outer_html)
print(f"html_tree {html_tree}")

html_tree.getpath(element)
xpath = html_tree.getroottree().getpath(element)
```

how can i getpath function to work or what is an alternative method to get the xpath?